# ElasticSearch - Search fails for 2 string fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running into search error - need some help. I have article index with id, title, artist, genre fields. When I run this query I get zero results-

POST /d3acampaign/article/_search

```
    {
       "query": {
            "filtered": {
                "query": {
                    "match": {"genre": "metal"}    
                },
                "filter": {
                    "term": {"artist": "Somanath"}         
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

But if I change the query to something like - 
POST /d3acampaign/article/_search

```
    {
       "query": {
            "filtered": {
                "query": {
                    "match": {"genre": "metal"}    
                },
                "filter": {
                    "term": {"id": "7"}         
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

i get following result -

```
    {
       "took": 1,
       "timed_out": false,
       "_shards": {
          "total": 5,
          "successful": 5,
          "failed": 0
       },
       "hits": {
          "total": 1,
          "max_score": 1.4054651,
          "hits": [
             {
                "_index": "d3acampaign",
                "_type": "article",
                "_id": "7",
                "_score": 1.4054651,
                "_source": {
                   "id": "7",
                   "title": "The Last Airbender",
                   "artist": "Somanath",
                   "genre": "metal"
                }
             }
          ]
       }
    }
```

Clarification - I am noticing search failing in case if I try against string e.g. artist, title

Answer (score 0):

The reason of you get empty hits is when you query by using `term query`, it will match the ***exact term*** in index includes ***uppercase***.

and the default analyzer will create index with lowercase.

> There are many ways to analyze text: the default standard analyzer
>   drops most punctuation, breaks up text into individual words, and
>   lower cases them. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

The solution:

```
   {
       "query": {
            "filtered": {
                "query": {
                    "match": {"genre": "metal"}    
                },
                "filter": {
                    "term": {"artist": "somanath"}  //to lower case      
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

The other solution is change your ***index mapping*** to ***not_analyzed*** for your index type.

The full example:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -XDELETE "localhost:9200/testindex"
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/testindex/?pretty" -d '
{
    "mappings":{
        "test":{
            "properties":{
                "name":{
                    "index":"not_analyzed",
                        "type":"string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'

curl -XGET "localhost:9200/testindex/_mapping?pretty"

curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/testindex/test/1" -d '{
    "name": "Jack"
}'

sleep 1
echo -e
echo -e
echo -e
echo -e "Filtered Query Search in not_analyzed index:"
echo -e

curl -XGET "localhost:9200/testindex/test/_search?pretty" -d '{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
                "filter": {
                    "term": {"name": "Jack"}  
                }

        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: From the [official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html): "Both HTTP GET and HTTP POST can be used to execute search with body. Since not all clients support GET with body, POST is allowed as well."

Comment: I have tried index mapping 'not_analyzed', still running into same problem. please confirm if mapping i am setting is correct,

Comment: @Guruprasad can you paste your mapping?

Comment: FilterContainer fc = null;

  TermFilter titleTF = new TermFilter()
  {
   Field = "title",
   Value = titleToMatch,
  };

  TermFilter artistTF = new TermFilter()
  {
   Field = "artist",
   Value = artistToMatch,
  };

  fc = titleTF & artistTF;

Comment: `code`   QueryContainer qc = new FilteredQuery() { Filter = fc };
  var searchRequest = new SearchRequest
  {
   SearchType = Elasticsearch.Net.SearchType.QueryAndFetch,
   Query = qc,
   Indices = new IndexNameMarker[] { database },
   Types = new TypeNameMarker[] { "article" },
  };
  
  var findArticles = client.SearchAsync<Article>(searchRequest);
  findArtices.Wait();

Comment: I havent changed my search request. How do you convert term to lower case?

Comment: Value = titleToMatch.lower() Value = artistToMatch.lower()